# Why does int = int * double give an error and int *= double does not (in Java)?

Tags: java, int, double, multiplication

Why does an assignment of the form int = int * double give an error, and an assignment of the form int *= double does not give an error (in Java)?

Example:

```
public class TestEmp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double e = 10;
        int r = 1; 
        r *= e;

        r = r * e;
        System.out.println("De uitkomst van r :" + r);

    }
}
```

`r *= e` is accepted and `r = r * e` isn't.  Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`r = r * e` gives you an error because the result of `r * e` is a `double` so there will be a loss of precision when you store it in an `int`.

`r *= e` does not give you an error because it is syntactic sugar for `r = (int)(r * e)` ([source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2)).

Answer (score 0):

It is because `r` and `e` are  different types. When using compound assignment operators such as `*=`, the types are [narrowly](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) converted behind the scenes (*implicitly*). The `*` operator does not implicitly convert, thus you must explicitly convert by casting inward:

```
r = (int) (r * e);
```